# Get 'schemeCategory20' is not exported from 'd3' for transform D3.js V.5.7 to React JS component

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am new to ReactJS and D3.js. I am trying to transform a D3.js Particle (https://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/21f99959d48dd0d0c746) to a react component. After I create a react app using create-react-app, when I import couple of dependencies got this error: 'schemeCategory20' is not exported from d3'.

The original file using like this for D3 v3:

```
var formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),
    format = function(d) { return formatNumber(d) + " TWh"; },
    color = d3.scale.category20();
```

what I use is like this (looks need to change d3.scale.category20() to d3.schemeCategory20 ?):

```
 let formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f")
    let format = function(d) { return formatNumber(d) + " TWh"; };
    let color = d3.schemeCategory20;
```

here is my import code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import * as d3 from "d3";
// customized sankey
import sankey from "./sankey";
import * as scale from "d3-scale";
import * as drag from "d3-drag";
```

Here is my part of package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "d3-drag": "^1.2.3",
    "d3-scale": "^2.1.2",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5"
  },
```

Does anyone know how import d3 correctly in Reactjs?
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: it is not part of d3v5 anymore, just look in d3v3 for the color codes used and just create a `d3.scaleOrdinal` with that array as range

Comment: Thank you!  Yeah, it helped. However, do you know if I need to import  "d3-scale" or "d3-drag"?